# How to list the configured repositories?

Tags: gradle, netbeans-plugins

How can I list all the repositories configured for a project?

Background: I have a pretty complex gradle build script and [cannot get my NetBeans to download the sources](https://github.com/hildo/netbeans-gradle-javaee-project/issues/19#issuecomment-133431188) for maven dependencies. In that issue-report I was suggested to double check the order in which `mavenCentral` is being imported.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is the code to list the loaded repositories (thanks [@kelemen](https://github.com/kelemen)):

```groovy
task listrepos {
    doLast {
        println "Repositories:"
        project.repositories.each { println "Name: " + it.name + "; url: " + it.url }
   }
}
```

After adding this code to the build script, execute `gradle listrepos` and voilà...

Comment: In addition, if you want to, for example, check if credentials are correctly set, you can print `it.credentials.username` and `it.credentials.password`

Comment: And for those of you who are fatigued from whatever this is intended to troubleshoot, don't forget you need to use gradle like you would for building (e.g. `-b path/to/build.gadle`, `./gradlew` and whatnot.

Answer (score 13):

If someone comes to this page looking for the Kotlin (build.gradle.kts) equivalent of @Alberto's answer, it would be done as follows:

```
tasks.register("listrepos") {
    doLast {
        println("Repositories:")
        project.repositories.map{it as MavenArtifactRepository}
            .forEach{
            println("Name: ${it.name}; url: ${it.url}")
        }
    }
}
```

Just as a heads up, the cast to a `MavenArtifactRepository` is required in the Kotlin version to get the `url` property.  This could be different for you if you are not adding Maven Repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use [Alberto's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413020/alberto) [task from his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143438/7653022) I was getting the following error as in my case I had a Plugin repository defined:

```
No such property: url for class: org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.PluginDependencyResolutionServices$PluginArtifactRepository
```

To avoid this error I have changed the task logic a bit:

```
task listrepos {
    doLast {
        println "Repositories:"
        project.repositories.each {
            if (it.name == '__plugin_repository__Gradle Central Plugin Repository') {
                println "Name: " + it.name + "; url: " + it.url
            } else {
                println "Name: " + it.displayName
            }
        }
    }
}
```