# How can I reuse an IvyPublication in a custom PublishToIvyRepository task?

Tags: gradle, ivy

I have a `build.gradle` file with an artifact I am publishing, following the guidelines given in the [Ivy publishing documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html).

```
publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            from components.java
            descriptor.withXml {
                asNode().info[0].appendNode("description", description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a separate [`PublishToIvyRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/ivy/tasks/PublishToIvyRepository.html) task, which I would like to configure so that it goes to a different repository that normal, but uses the same publication as the above code. My initial attempt is this:

```
task publishToIvyLocal(type: PublishToIvyRepository) {
    repository = mySpecialRepository
    publication = project.publishing.publications[0]
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. If I put it before the `publishing {}` block above, I get the following error:

> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

I'm guessing that `project.publishing.publications[0]` isn't the best way to reuse this publication.

How can I reuse an IvyPublication in a custom PublishToIvyRepository task?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a `PublishToIvyRepository` task on your own.

> Applying the `'ivy-publish'` plugin does the following:
>
> - [...]
> - Establishes a rule to automatically create a `PublishToIvyRepository` task for the combination of each `IvyPublication` added (see Section 35.2, “Publications”), with each `IvyArtifactRepository` added (see Section 35.3, “Repositories”).

So, simply add your publication with your two repositories and two tasks will be created, one to publish the publication for each repository.

> The created task is named `publish«PUBNAME»PublicationTo«REPONAME»Repository`, which is `publishIvyJavaPublicationToIvyRepository` for this example.

Some example code:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mySpecial(IvyPublication) {
            // configure publication
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ivy {
            name = 'first'
            // configure first repository
        }
        ivy {
            name = 'second'
            // configure second repository
        }
    }
}
```

This should create the following tasks:

- `publishMySpecialPublicationToFirstRepository`
- `publishMySpecialPublicationToSecondRepository`

Regarding the repository name:

> The name for this repository. A name must be unique amongst a repository set. A default name is provided for the repository if none is provided.

Comment: I had no idea it was even possible. I wish the official documentation did a better job of explaining it.

Comment: Is there something special you have to do to generate the `publishMySpecialPublicationToFirstRepository` task? It isn't showing up in `gradlew tasks`, but does show up when I have Gradle [print out the connected repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143438/531762).

Comment: Did you specify the repository in the project repository handler (`repositories { ... }`) or in the publishing repository handler (`publishing.repositories { ... }`)?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I had it in `repositories { ... }`. Now it shows up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code sample I agree with lu.koerfer's answer but in case if you really need a custom publication task you can use [`project.afterEvaluate`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:afterEvaluate(groovy.lang.Closure)) to access the `publishing` container after it has been configured:

```
project.afterEvaluate
{
    customPublicationTask.publication = project.publishing.publications["ivy"]
    // a publication can be accessed by its name
}
```