# How to list the buildscript repositories in Gradle

Tags: gradle

How can I list all the repositories available to the project's buildscript?

I'm migrating some projects from very simple Gradle builds to start using some custom platforms and convention plugins but I'm having some trouble importing some of those artifacts into the buildscript.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143437/how-to-list-the-configured-repositories) and tried the following:

```java
tasks.register("listrepos") {
    doLast {
        println("Repositories:")
        project.buildscript.repositories.map { it as MavenArtifactRepository }
            .forEach { println("Name: ${it.name}; url: ${it.url}") }
    }
}
```

But the list is always empty.

It's awkward because I was expecting at least the `gradlePluginPortal()` repository to be listed here.

**EDIT:**

After [@PrasadU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5845802/prasadu)'s answer I added the following snipped to my `build.gradle.kts` file. I just updated it to the Kotlin DSL syntax:

```java
project.afterEvaluate {
    println("Running project afterEvaluate")
    project.buildscript.repositories.asMap.forEach { (name, repo) ->
        println("$name >> ${repo.name}")
    }
}
```

The problem is that `project.buildscript.repositories.asMap` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need a task for that ...

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.buildscript.repositories.getAsMap().forEach {
        name, repo -> println("$name >> ${repo.properties.displayName}")
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer. But the set of repositories is empty. That's probably why I'm having trouble resolving my artifacts. But the repositories are declared and I'm surely resolving some artifacts. That list shouldn't be empty, right?